# full_clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I'm currently using django version 2.2.4 and trying to create an edit button that will update my models. When trying to save the updated value an TypeError occured which it stated that "full_clean() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". I can't seem to detect any error from my codes. Thanks in advance for helping me.

my views.py file

```
def lab_edit(request, pk, template_name='webapp/lab_edit.html'):
    lab= get_object_or_404(Labs, pk=pk)
    form = LabForm(request.POST or None, instance=Labs)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('lab')
        return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

my lab_edit.html file

```
<div class='container'>
<h2>EDIT LAB</h2>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

my LabForm

```
 class LabForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
          model = Labs
          fields = ('labcode', 'name','administrator')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `LabForm` gets as `instance=` the model *class*, not a model object. You should fix that by passing `lab` instead:

```
def lab_edit(request, pk, template_name='webapp/lab_edit.html'):
    lab = get_object_or_404(Labs, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LabForm(request.POST, instance=lab)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return redirect('lab')
    else:
        form = LabForm(instance=lab)
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

By passing a reference to the *class* , you have basically called `full_clean` on the class, hence the error.

Note that you should *not* use `request.POST or None` since an empty POST request can still be a valid POST request.